# How did the message, "This post is related to a rapidly changing event" appear?

Tags: support, post-notices

On Travel.SE, there was a hot network question about the United Kingdom leaving the European Union. The vote was yesterday, and other developments are of course possible, so it is understandable why the message, "This post is related to a rapidly changing event" would be there, but what is the process for it, or a similar message to appear?

[image]

I'm assuming a moderator can add the message, similarly to how they can lock a post or add special tags, but can they put whatever message they want below a post, or is it limited to a pre-set list of messages? (or, am I totally wrong about this being a moderator's doing?)

Comment: It's a mod message. Looking for a related post/dupe on this.

Comment: that was it, thanks for the link! (so yes, it seems there is a per set list of messages a moderator can add)